# Problem about detecting and mounting devices

Tags: 14.04, usb, usb-drive, dmesg

The device I want to mount is Nokia 130. `lsusb` or `lsblk` cannot find it, but `dmesg` will, some part of the output is following:

```
[30415.272150] usb 3-2: new full-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[30415.332957] usb 3-2: New USB device found, idVendor=0421, idProduct=069a
[30415.332963] usb 3-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[30415.332967] usb 3-2: Product: Nokia 130 (RM-1035)
[30415.332970] usb 3-2: Manufacturer: Nokia
[30419.295175] usb 3-2: USB disconnect, device number 4
[30420.004139] usb 3-2: new full-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[30420.071343] usb 3-2: New USB device found, idVendor=0421, idProduct=06fb
[30420.071349] usb 3-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=4
[30420.071353] usb 3-2: Product: Nokia 130 (RM-1035)
[30420.071356] usb 3-2: Manufacturer: Nokia
[30420.071359] usb 3-2: SerialNumber: 537595606123480
[30420.121633] usb-storage 3-2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[30420.121756] scsi7 : usb-storage 3-2:1.0
[30420.121876] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
[30420.936719] usb 3-2: USB disconnect, device number 5
[31462.012145] usb 3-2: new full-speed USB device number 6 using xhci_hcd
[31462.072400] usb 3-2: New USB device found, idVendor=0421, idProduct=069a
[31462.072406] usb 3-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[31462.072410] usb 3-2: Product: Nokia 130 (RM-1035)
[31462.072413] usb 3-2: Manufacturer: Nokia
[31465.735034] usb 3-2: USB disconnect, device number 6
[31466.448144] usb 3-2: new full-speed USB device number 7 using xhci_hcd
[31466.515821] usb 3-2: New USB device found, idVendor=0421, idProduct=06fb
[31466.515827] usb 3-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=4
[31466.515831] usb 3-2: Product: Nokia 130 (RM-1035)
[31466.515834] usb 3-2: Manufacturer: Nokia
[31466.515837] usb 3-2: SerialNumber: 537595606123480
[31466.525872] usb-storage 3-2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[31466.526002] scsi8 : usb-storage 3-2:1.0
[31467.141983] usb 3-2: USB disconnect, device number 7
[31563.423080] systemd-hostnamed[4075]: Warning: nss-myhostname is not installed. Changing the local hostname might make it unresolveable. Please install nss-myhostname!
[31628.432264] usb 2-1.2: new full-speed USB device number 3 using ehci-pci
[31628.527422] usb 2-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=0421, idProduct=069a
[31628.527428] usb 2-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[31628.527432] usb 2-1.2: Product: Nokia 130 (RM-1035)
[31628.527435] usb 2-1.2: Manufacturer: Nokia
[31632.034964] usb 2-1.2: USB disconnect, device number 3
[31632.680129] usb 2-1.2: new full-speed USB device number 4 using ehci-pci
[31632.775804] usb 2-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=0421, idProduct=06fb
[31632.775810] usb 2-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=4
[31632.775814] usb 2-1.2: Product: Nokia 130 (RM-1035)
[31632.775817] usb 2-1.2: Manufacturer: Nokia
[31632.775820] usb 2-1.2: SerialNumber: 537595606123480
[31632.776848] usb-storage 2-1.2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[31632.776985] scsi9 : usb-storage 2-1.2:1.0
[31633.597537] usb 2-1.2: USB disconnect, device number 4
[31726.292158] usb 3-2: new full-speed USB device number 8 using xhci_hcd
[31726.353181] usb 3-2: New USB device found, idVendor=0421, idProduct=069a
[31726.353188] usb 3-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[31726.353191] usb 3-2: Product: Nokia 130 (RM-1035)
[31726.353194] usb 3-2: Manufacturer: Nokia
[31730.089631] usb 3-2: USB disconnect, device number 8
[31730.804146] usb 3-2: new full-speed USB device number 9 using xhci_hcd
[31730.871595] usb 3-2: New USB device found, idVendor=0421, idProduct=06fb
[31730.871601] usb 3-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=4
[31730.871605] usb 3-2: Product: Nokia 130 (RM-1035)
[31730.871608] usb 3-2: Manufacturer: Nokia
[31730.871611] usb 3-2: SerialNumber: 537595606123480
[31730.881652] usb-storage 3-2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[31730.881908] scsi10 : usb-storage 3-2:1.0
[31731.130632] usb 3-2: USB disconnect, device number 9
[31865.912155] usb 3-2: new full-speed USB device number 10 using xhci_hcd
[31865.973102] usb 3-2: New USB device found, idVendor=0421, idProduct=069a
[31865.973109] usb 3-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[31865.973113] usb 3-2: Product: Nokia 130 (RM-1035)
[31865.973116] usb 3-2: Manufacturer: Nokia
[31869.311146] usb 3-2: USB disconnect, device number 10
[31870.024148] usb 3-2: new full-speed USB device number 11 using xhci_hcd
[31870.091562] usb 3-2: New USB device found, idVendor=0421, idProduct=06fb
[31870.091568] usb 3-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=4
[31870.091572] usb 3-2: Product: Nokia 130 (RM-1035)
[31870.091575] usb 3-2: Manufacturer: Nokia
[31870.091578] usb 3-2: SerialNumber: 537595606123480
[31870.101626] usb-storage 3-2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[31870.101880] scsi11 : usb-storage 3-2:1.0
[31870.321916] usb 3-2: USB disconnect, device number 11
[32442.512985] systemd-hostnamed[4657]: Warning: nss-myhostname is not installed. Changing the local hostname might make it unresolveable. Please install nss-myhostname!
[32510.816153] usb 3-2: new full-speed USB device number 12 using xhci_hcd
[32510.876515] usb 3-2: New USB device found, idVendor=0421, idProduct=069a
[32510.876521] usb 3-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[32510.876525] usb 3-2: Product: Nokia 130 (RM-1035)
[32510.876529] usb 3-2: Manufacturer: Nokia
[32517.255265] usb 3-2: USB disconnect, device number 12
[32517.968141] usb 3-2: new full-speed USB device number 13 using xhci_hcd
[32518.035588] usb 3-2: New USB device found, idVendor=0421, idProduct=06fb
[32518.035594] usb 3-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=4
[32518.035598] usb 3-2: Product: Nokia 130 (RM-1035)
[32518.035601] usb 3-2: Manufacturer: Nokia
[32518.035604] usb 3-2: SerialNumber: 537595606123480
[32518.045645] usb-storage 3-2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[32518.045925] scsi12 : usb-storage 3-2:1.0
[32518.498550] usb 3-2: USB disconnect, device number 13
```

How can I mount it?